# Use Ternary operator instead of if..else in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ternary-operator

Instead of if...else statement how to do using ternary operation or any alternative way to simplify code in javascript

```
if(req.query.pr=="trans"){
    util.transUrl(req.originalUrl).then(param => {
      res.redirect(param);
    })
  }
  else if(req.query.pr=="inst"){
    util.instaUrl(req.originalUrl).then(param => {
      res.redirect(param);
    })
  }
  else{
    res.status(400).send("Contact the editor of the originating page.")
  }
```

Comment: If there are multiple lines of code to be executed, if else if loop is better readable than ternary operators

Comment: Try to read more about ternary operators. Here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator 
and 
https://codeburst.io/javascript-the-conditional-ternary-operator-explained-cac7218beeff

Then decide whether to use it or not.

Comment: The conditional operator is not very appropriate here. I suppose the first `if` and `else if` could be condensed, but I prefer the current version, it's more readable. To make things a bit more DRY you could define a function `param => res.redirect(param)`

Comment: Ternary operators are better to be used for simplest (one liners) if...else conditions. if you want to use it just for reducing number of lines  then you can have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to write a conditional statement in JS. However, if there are multiple statements I would say you should stick to `if` `else if` `else`. But if you want to see other approaches, here they are:

> Using **Ternary operator `? :`**

```
const {pr} = req.query
pr === 'trans'
? util.transUrl(req.originalUrl).then(param => 
      res.redirect(param)
  )
: pr === 'inst'
? util.instaUrl(req.originalUrl).then(param => 
      res.redirect(param)
  )
: res.status(400).send('Contact the editor of the originating page.')
```

> Using **Gate logic `&& ||`**

```
const {pr} = req.query
(pr === 'trans' && 
    util.transUrl(req.originalUrl).then(param => 
        res.redirect(param))
) ||
(pr=== 'inst' && 
    util.instaUrl(req.originalUrl).then(param => 
        res.redirect(param))
) || 
res.status(400).send('Contact the editor of the originating page.')
```

Now, Looking at your code, here **if and else if statements are similar**. So you can avoid `else if` using ternary operator like this:

```
const {pr} = req.query
if(pr === 'trans' || pr === 'inst'){
    util[pr === 'trans' ? 'transUrl' : 'instaUrl'](req.originalUrl)
    .then(param => res.redirect(param))
}
else{
    res.status(400).send('Contact the editor of the originating page.')
}
```

**Just one FYI**: *Please consider using `===` instead of `==` whenever you are comparing strings and there is no need of coercion.*

Comment: No actually I was wrong sorry, their variable is `inst` while the key is `instaURL`, there is an `a` that needs to be added by some logic, better keep the whole thing as you did then, even though they were originally checking if `pr` was `"inst"`,  while you are handling all non `"trans"` as `"inst"`